# Java - Sending values from Subclass to Superclass

Tags: java, superclass

I'm having some trobles sending an value from my subclass to my superclass.

E.x:

```
public class A {
protected int Age;
   public void printAge(){
     System.out.println(Age);
   }
}
public class B extends A {
   public void changeAge(){
      Age = 11;
   }
}
```

I want the printAge metod to print '11', is this possible? To change the value of an variable from the Superclass?

I'm very new to Java.

Comment: Like in B b = new B(); b.changeAge(); b.printAge();

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible, your code [is working](http://ideone.com/P6Ytt6).

I.e. this will actually print '11':

```
B b = new B();
b.changeAge();
b.printAge();
```